# Why evenafter edit also question still on hold?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I asked a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/663278/how-can-i-use-math-symbols-in-ubuntu) which was kept on hold.But even after edit also why it is still on hold?

Comment: Your question is now open again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reopened it because there is a legitimate question in there.

Part of it can be answered *for* Math.SE (use MathJAX notation) but there are simpler notations that would still apply outside of Math.SE that would be helpful to know.

With that in mind, please answer the question you've been asked under Liso's answer.