# Why do I see wrong suggestion for possible answer above my question?

Tags: support, duplicates

Up above my question I see the heading that "this question may already have an answer."

[image: Eg. -]

- the link provided in this heading does not give answer to my question. More interestingly, I mention that link (question) in my own question and I do explain how that does not give me the correct answer. What should do in such a case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is quite simple (in my opinion) :

Your question may have appeared as duplicate of a linked question even though you have a different problem.

Edit your question and flag it to moderator's intervention or vote to reopen it.

Please refer my [question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14295/why-evenafter-edit-also-question-still-on-hold).

If you edit and convey your actual problem properly (in case it is different and not a duplicate) your question has a pretty good chance te be reopened.